# Swift 3 - Popup when certain amount of actions are made

Tags: ios, swift

I am wondering if anyone knows how to create a popup when a user does a certain amount of actions.
For example if a user presses any button say 3 times, a popup comes up.

Comment: Sure have but I can't find anything.

Comment: Add a counter "var counter:Int = 0". Then increment the count each button press in the action method. Then at the end of the method check the count. If it is above 3 times display the popup (Could use UIAlertViewController or a pod for that).

Comment: Okay thank you, I will give that a go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, create an integer with an initial value of zero. Every time the button is pressed, increment one to this integer. At the end of the function, check whether this integer is equal to three and if so, present the alert.

```
var counter = 0

@IBAction func buttonPress(_ sender: Any) {
    counter += 1

    if counter == 3 {
        counter = 0
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Pressed 3 Times", message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```